# How to download minute to minute stock data in given time range on python

Tags: python, event-handling, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

I am trying to

1) Create a file which will write minute to minute data into csv file for a stock through ystockquote.

2) Start at a specific given time to specific end time .

3) For each minute, I write the data from get_price_time function and store it into the csv file.

4) Use symbol, start_specific_time, end_specific_time, filename, datarate as inputs.

5) I created file and close the file. At start_specific_time create a csv file and at the end_specific_time close the csv file.

I need to create a scheduler for all of this. I am stuck at scheduler.Here is my code

```
import ystockquote

import sched, time

from sys import argv

script, symbol, start_specific_time, end_specific_time, filename, datarate = argv

def get_price_time(symbol):
    price = ystockquote.get_price(symbol)
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    return [symbol, price, current_time]

def create_file(filename):
    return open(filename,'w')

def close_file(target):
    target.close()

def write_data_to_file(target, data):
    target.write(data[0])# first element of list which is symbol
    target.write(",")
    target.write(data[1])# 2nd element of list which is price
    target.write(",")
    target.write(str(data[2])) # 3rd element date which is string
    target.write ("\n") # create new line 

def create_scheduler
```

Comment: Slight aside: you probably want to `write(',',join([str(x) for x in data]))` in your `write_to_file` function.

Comment: @BenDundee Thank You I will reflect it in my code.

Comment: I meant, of course: `','.join(...)`

Comment: Are you set on writing your own scheduler? There's `chron` if you're on UNIX, there's a similar app under Windows. I just paid $10 for a scheduler called Lingon from the Mac App store.

Comment: @BenDundee Do you mean `cron`? (which btw, is already installed on your OS X box http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2001020700163714)